# Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused in 16.04

Tags: upstart

I am trying to start my `Dynatrace Service` from `init.d` folder , whenever i am trying to start the servers i am getting the

```
/com/ubuntu/upstart: connection refused
```

please let me know if i need to change any configuration settings

Comment: Please run `sudo systemctl start dynatrace` and check the status with `systemctl status dynatrace`

Answer (score 1):

To check if it's there:

```
sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i dynatrace
```

To start:

```
sudo systemctl start dynatrace
```

To check status:

```
systemctl status dynatrace
```

To enable at boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable dynatarce
```